# Countable Unions of Pair-wise Disjoint Infinite Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: number-theory

Let $\left\{ \left(a_{n},b_{n},\kappa_{n}\right)\right\} _{n\geq1}$
  be an infinite sequence of triples of non-negative integers satisfying $0\leq b_{n}\leq a_{n}-1$ for all $n$. Then, for each $n$, let $P_{n}$ denote the infinite arithmetic progression: $$P_{n}=\left\{ a_{n}k+b_{n}:k\geq\kappa_{n}\right\}$$ and let: $$P=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{n}$$

Now, supposing that $P_{n}\cap P_{m}=\varnothing$ for all distinct $m,n\geq1$, does there exist a finite set $Q$ and finitely many infinite arithmetic progressions $\left\{ P_{j}^{\prime}\right\} _{j\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,J\right\} }$ so that: $$Q\cap P_{j}^{\prime}=P_{j}^{\prime}\cap P_{k}^{\prime}=\varnothing$$
  for all distinct $j,k\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,J\right\}$, and which satisfy:$$P=Q\cup\bigcup_{j=1}^{J}P_{j}^{\prime}$$
 ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't ask if I already knew the answer. Personally, I would very, very much like it to be true, but—as always—I fear that there might be a counter-example lurking somewhere. Hence, I turn to the internet, in the hopes of finding someone that has dealt with this question before.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't ask if you knew the answer.  I want to know what you think about this problem, as you have not said anything about (a) why you think it might be true, (b) why you think it might not be true, or (c) why you care.  Sharing your thoughts, efforts and motivations will make some people more likely to answer your request for help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are uncountably many of the first type of $P.$ For example the sets $P=\bigcup_{k,n\geq 0}(1+2(k+c_n))2^n$ for any $\{0,1\}$-valued sequence $c_n$ are distinct. But there are countably many of the second type of $P.$

For an explicit counterexample, consider the set of numbers that are not powers of two. This can be expressed as the union of the disjoint arithmetic progressions $((1+2k)2^n)_{k\geq 1}$ for $n\geq 0.$ But the complement of any union of finitely many arithmetic progressions will be eventually periodic, which means it is either bounded or [syndetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndetic_set), but the powers of two are neither bounded nor syndetic.